# How to make this sentence more concise?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Sentence:

> Set the total votes to the value of the highest For plus Against votes

---

**Background**

Basically, there is a Total Votes textbox and a table with columns Age, For and Against :

```
| Age |For votes|Against votes|
| ----|---------|-----------|
|50   | 2000    | 3000      |
|60   | 3000    | 8000      |
```

There is a function that sets the value of the Total Votes textbox to the highest value of For plus Against votes of a certain row when compared with values of For plus against votes in other rows. In the above table, this value would be 11000 (3000 + 8000). I want to describe this function in simple layman terms.

I'm not sure whether simple users would understand *Set the total votes to the value of the highest For plus Against votes*. I think there is something missing in relation to the Age column and hence, it isn't clear enough.

Comment: Given a bunch of numbers (e.g., 42, 17, 83, 95, 60), set the total to the largest one (95). ... ... ... Why are you even using the word "total" when you mean *maximum*?

Comment: @Scott because the primary function of Total Votes textbox is for users to set the total number of votes to be registered as they wished. The maximum function is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *"'Total Votes' is the number of votes cast, both For and Against, by the age group with the biggest response"*?

However I find the term "Total Votes" confusing in this context as I would expect that to be the number of votes cast overall (that is the sum of the contents of both For and Against cells for all rows). Can I suggest that you use something like "Best Response" instead of "Total Votes"? You could then expand on that by using my suggestion above replacing "Total Votes" with "Best Response".

Comment: Nice! For me, this is more clear and concise than the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

*'Total votes' is the highest value among all rows of the sum of 'for votes' and 'against votes' for each row* is completely clear and sufficiently short.

Comment: Slight tweaks for your consideration: 'Total votes' is the highest value among all rows of the sum of 'for votes' and 'against votes' for each row.

Comment: Nice. I can vote this. Have a good night.